# Usercontrol containing ScrollViewer has disabled scrollbar

Tags: xaml, scroll, user-controls, scrollbar

I have implemented a user control which contains a grid inside a ScrollViewer. There is no functional code behind. If the XAML (see below) is used in an application (so between `<Window></Window>`) it works as expected. The vertical scroll bar appears if the row heights are made large enough and the lower rows can be scrolled up. However if exactly the same XAML is used as part of a user control (so between `<UserControl></UserControl>`) it works in the same way except the scroll bar is disabled. The ScrollViewer, when examined shows that IsEnabled is true. Any idea why this control cannot be selected?

```
    <Canvas Name="MyCanvas">
        <Canvas Name="GridHeaderCanvas"
                Background="Black"
                Width="345"
                Height="480"
                Canvas.Top="0">
            <Label Content="Add" Background="BlanchedAlmond" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="35" Height="25" Canvas.Top="3" Canvas.Left="3"></Label>
            <Label Content="Name" Background="PowderBlue" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="245" Height="25" Canvas.Top="3" Canvas.Left="41"></Label>
            <Label Content="Val" Background="PowderBlue" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Width="35" Height="25" Canvas.Top="3" Canvas.Left="290"></Label>
            <ScrollViewer x:Name="MyScrollViewer"
                Canvas.Top="30"
                Canvas.Left="3"
                Height="440"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled"
                VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                <Grid x:Name="GridCanvas"
                        Background="Black">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="35" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="245" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="35" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="200" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="200" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="200" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="200" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <Label Content="Val0" Background="PowderBlue" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0"></Label>
                    <Label Content="Val0" Background="PowderBlue" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0"></Label>
                    <Label Content="Val0" Background="PowderBlue" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="0"></Label>
                    <Label Content="Val1" Background="Pink" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1"></Label>
                    <Label Content="Val1" Background="Pink" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"></Label>
                    <Label Content="Val1" Background="Pink" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1"></Label>
                    <Label Content="Val2" Background="Yellow" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="2"></Label>
                    <Label Content="Val2" Background="Yellow" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2"></Label>
                    <Label Content="Val2" Background="Yellow" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"></Label>
                    <Label Content="Val3" Background="Pink" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="3"></Label>
                    <Label Content="Val3" Background="Pink" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="3"></Label>
                    <Label Content="Val3" Background="Pink" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="3"></Label>
                </Grid>
            </ScrollViewer>
        </Canvas>
        <Canvas Name="ComponentCanvas"
                Width="300"
                Height="480"
                Background="LightSkyBlue"
                Canvas.Top="0"
                Canvas.Left="350">
            <StackPanel
                Name="ControlPanel"
                Canvas.Top="10"
                Canvas.Left="10">
            </StackPanel>
        </Canvas>
    </Canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

It took a while but the answer is that the page that hosted this control was of type Canvas. This Canvas had no name, if a name was given the problem disappeared.